# Is it possible to get the INT implant without leveling?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In trying for a perfect character  everyone keeps going for 10 int but would it be possible to get the implant without leveling?

Can you go to the clinic and then return to good springs and start the quests?

would it be possible to assemble 2000caps and go into Vegas to get the remainder or would entering Vegas disrupt your quest line (like how fallout 3 could make you miss a lot of quests if you talked to doctor li in rivit city when you picked the int bobble head up).

And any tips on getting 2000caps without leveling?

Comment: So the idea is that you take 1 point from `INT` in to something else, and then rush to get the `INT` implant? Why not keep the point in `INT` and rush to get the `{otherStat}` implant? Or just go the latter without having to rush so much?

Comment: @DMA57361 Because 10 is the maximum any base stat like Int can become. If you start off at 10, you effectively render the int implant useless. But if you start off at 9 and don't get the implant before leveling even once, you cannot get the maximum amount of attribute points for the ones like Sneak or Medicine or the like.

Comment: Ah, good point. I got the not leveling to not lose skill points, but it hadn't dawned on me that as long as your `END` is high enough to get all implants, starting with one of the stats at 10 nullifies the potential +1 it's implant can provide. Also, have you seen http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10308/is-it-possible-to-reach-max-stats-in-fallout-new-vegas ?

Comment: @DMA57361 yes, i did see that one, and they all start off at 10base INT. it seems like a waste of an implant chance (there is only 9 implants in the game, so it is possible to get all of them even if you get all 7 special and the healing and dt ones.)

Comment: It should be noted that there's no longer any real reason to do this. With the additional levels and skill books from the DLC, you can max all skills by the early 40's with an INT of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several guides discussing this, and there should be some youtube videos as well: http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/rpg/falloutnewvegas/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-57467981&pid=959557

The quick version involves:

- Picking up the Goodsprings snowglobe
- Ignoring all quests
- Looting the Goodsprings Schoolhouse
- Using Stealth Boys to sneak past the Deathclaws on your way north
- Selling everything you find that is not nailed
- Purchasing a fake passport into The Strip
- Having enough funds to purchase the Intelligence Implant

Comment: You shouldn't even need to get into the Strip -  the gambling limit at the Atomic Wrangler in Freeside is more than high enough to cover early Implant costs.

Comment: i forgot about the wrangler. selling the snowglobe at the strip would have come a long way, but i'd prefer not going into vegas.

Comment: one point to note though, doing 10 plays at slots nets you 100xp, and you level to level 2 with 200xp. entering the Tops casino gives you 1000xp as well. but missions accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Do Andy and Charlie in Novac: it doesn't give you any XP and you can loot the dead NCR people. You can then take Monorail from the NCR camp to the Strip, get the Mormon Fort snow globe so that you have that with the one you got from Goodsprings, and then turn those in for 4000 caps.

Answer (score 0):

You can amass a good amount of caps by doing the merchant glitch then try to make it to [New Vegas Medical Clinic](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/New_Vegas_Medical_Clinic) with lots of stimpaks you got using the same glitch. You need to set your initial INT to 9 and if you could set END as well, since this will be your final stats when you travel far off Goodspring.

Comment: You dont need to level up to do the merchant glitch... Just need an early broken down weapon ( 0% ) stat

Answer (score 0):

Play caravan with the store owner in novac or other npcs until you have enough money. its hard to lose at and you can save before each game so you can just load if you lose. Always raise the bet to get the most money. Might be easier than going all the way to new vegas.